# Concatenation precedence in case of std::string and const char

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it ok to write the following code?

```
std::string first = "str";
"1" + first + "2" + std::to_string(1).c_str();
```

Will `first` be concatenated with "2" before "2 + std::to_string" concatenation, so there will be no "pointers concatenation" error?

Comment: You could always compile it and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition is left-associative, so that's

```
(("1" + first) + "2") + std::to_string(1).c_str();
```

In other words, `first` will not be concatenated with `"2"`, and neither will `"2"` (fail to) be concatenated with `std::to_string(1).c_str()`.